# What does "the rib place" mean?

Tags: american-english

I am reading a play and I have problem with some word combinations, especially with this one: "rib place".

> This was from Longhorn's, the rib place. Over on 22nd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like a restaurant that serves ribs, i.e. a steakhouse kind of place.  This is backed up by the name, 'Longhorn's', since a longhorn is a breed of cattle.

Comment: The term "rib place" is fairly common where I'm from (Chicago, Midwest), and means a steakhouse specializing in barbecued ribs. It may have come from one of the local restaurants (Carson's, The Place for Ribs). By the way, Longhorn's Steakhouse is a chain of steak restaurants.